# glyphicon-search not coming inside the form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I want the glyphicon-search icon to be on the rightmost side inside the form but it is not coming inside the form.Can anyone tell how this can be done?

Well..cant we override glyhicon-search class to achieve the goal?If yes, then how(Im trying to do that but I am not achieving the desired result especially on shrinking the webpage)?

```
 <div  class="bar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="logo">  
            <a href="main.php">XYZ</a>
        </div>
        <div  class="col-xs-5 right-inner-addon ">
        <form class="form-inline" role="form">
             <div class="form-group has-feedback">
               <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-11">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess4">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span></div></div></div>
             </div>
        </form>
    </div>   
</div>

    .right-inner-addon {
        padding-top: 8px;
        padding-left:30px;

    }
    .right-inner-addon input {
        height: 30px;
        padding: 0px 10px;
    }
    .right-inner-addon i {
        position: relative;
        right: 0px;
        padding: 10px 12px;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .form-control{
        min-width: 400px; 
        max-width: 400px; 
        top: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply it as a background-iamge to the input: `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess4">` Or gieve the icon element a display:block  / inline-block property.